# How can i dynamically create a Time Interval for my Scripts in NodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have some functions that use intervals to be executed like every 5min or 1 day etc. Currently i would like to create  function that returns a Time frame in Sec based on the user selection. Currently i do this via a config file that exports the time frame in secs.  What i am looking for is something like
1min = 1 * (60*100) where I check if its min, hr, day, week or month and then multiply with the nbr. The question is is there a way to split between nbr and char ? or what else would be the best approach ?

```
const oneminute = 1 * 60 * 1000;
const fiveminutes = 5 * 60 * 1000;
const tenminutes = 10 * 60 * 1000;
const thirtyminutes = 30 * 60 * 1000
const onehour = 60 * 60 * 1000
const oneday = 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
const thirtydays = 30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000
const oneweek = 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000


module.exports = {
    oneminute,
    fiveminutes,
    tenminutes,
    thirtyminutes,
    onehour,
    oneday,
    thirtydays,
    oneweek
}
```

Comment: There are already [npm packages](https://www.npmjs.com/package/parse-duration) out there to convert Strings like `1m`, `5 hours 5 mins`, etc, to milliseconds, seconds, or other. You can even customize the unit strings. Do you really need to reinvent the wheel?

Comment: I didn't find a package that did that, but if you can point me to some that will be helpful.

Comment: I did, just click on the link 

Comment: Thanks that works great, if you change your comment to an answer i can acceopt and close